# How to normalise changes that occur over time spans of different duration?

Tags: time-series, normalization, temporal-difference

I want to compare changes in a variable that occur over time spans of different duration.

Here is a hypothetical example:
Precipitation in Region A decreased by 300 mm (from 1000 mm to 700 mm) over a 75-year period. Precipitation in Region B decreased by 250 mm (from 900 mm to 650 mm) over a 60-year period.

Is there a way to normalise the different lengths of the two time spans so that I can compare the changes in the variable?

(I thought about calculating rates of change (Change/Number of years). However, rates of change still contain the signal of the original time span. The duration directly influences the magnitude of the calculated rates. The longer the time span, the lower are the calculated rates of change; and the shorter the time span, the higher are the calculated rates of change. So rates of change are still not normalised, and therefore not comparable. I'm looking for a way to eliminate the influence of the different time spans completely.)

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you are going to do with this data afterwards. If you can explain the problem/application, it will be easier to give some recommendations.

The simplest option would be to get both values to "change or unit time". In other words, you divide your overall change by the time (in required units):
Region A: 300/75 = 4 mm/year
Region B: 250/60 $\approx$ 4.17 mm/year.

So, you can see, that Region B had a faster change in average.

Please, note, that the word average here is the key. That assumes that the rate of change is constant (or the change is linear). To fit a more complex function with more than 1 parameter (e.g. polynomial), you will obviously need more points for each region (or make extra assumptions).

Comment: Many thanks for your comment. Yes, I thought about calculating rates of change (Change/Number of years). However, rates of change still contain the signal of the original time span. The duration directly influences the magnitude of the calculated rates. The longer the time span, the lower are the calculated rates of change; and the shorter the time span, the higher are the calculated rates of change. So rates of change are still not normalised. (Or am I wrong? I'm not a statistician, which is why I posted my question to this forum.)

Comment: I'm looking for a way to eliminate the influence of the different time spans in order to make the changes in my variable comparable.

Comment: No, rate of change is normalised by time. It is not that you higher rate for shorter period of time because the time span is shorter. You have a higher rate because the change is faster.

Comment: Let's get away from your problem and get a simple example. Let's imagine two cars. One drove 300 m (note the dimension of length here) in 75 second, and another one drove 250 meters in 60 seconds. The first car has an average speed of 4 m/s (dimension of length over time, or length driven in a unit of time, i.e. second). The second car has a speed of approximately 4.17 m/s. Now, if each car drives for 60 seconds with corresponding speed, the first car will go 240 metres, and second car will do 250 metres. So, the speed is change over the same unit of time (be it second, year or million years).

Comment: Thanks for this!